# jQuery datepicker not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a very annoying problem with jQuery and the datepicker from jQuery-UI.

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
<!--
        $(function(){
            $("#startdate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy'});
        });
// -->
    /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

And here the HTML part:

```
<input type="text" name="tx_cal_controller[startdate]" id="startdate" readonly="readonly">
```

The necessary JavaScript libraries are included in the header:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://foo.bar/fileadmin/res/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js?1328657226" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But there is no datepicker when I click on the input field. I would really appreciate it, if anyone could give me a hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe cause input is readonly?

Comment: Have you tried removing the <!-- and CDATA sections around the script?  BTW, the date format should be dd.mm.yy, since y means 2 digit year and yy means 4 digit year.

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/46uJy/
Try debugging the js and see if any errors occur.

Comment: @PHeiberg That's a really cool tool! No errors occur when debugging with Chrome ;(

Comment: Stupid question, but have you included the datepicker in your custom jQuery UI? Try with the full CDN version of UI:  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Sure. I was using the lib from Google before. I also thought about the datepicker included in the lib, so I made my custom jQuery-UI and included it. Still not working...

Comment: I am now using the full CDN version of jQuery-UI from the Google servers. Nothing changed

Comment: Since it's obviously the correct code, the only more advice I can give is that you start with a page containing only the input and the datepicker script (if that doesn't work on your machine something is seriously broken) and add the other stuff  to the page until it breaks.

Comment: There is a problem with my div tags and the z-index attributes. So the problem is not related to JavaScript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. There was a problem with the div of the datepicker. I had to include my own jQuery-UI package and modify it, so that when the input field gets clicked, the z-index of the datepicker gets higher (>1000) than the one of the other content divs and therefore visible.